# Why doesn't ondragover work in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I followed a tutorial on making a file uploader using javascript, and I got it to work and so I thought it would be better as a jQuery plugin so that I can use it on different elements on my page. So I started porting the code over to my plugin, and run into a problem.

Normally you can use jQuery and javascript, but for some reason ondragover is not working in my plugin.

```
;(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.asiLoader = function() {
        var base=$(this);

        base.ondragover=function(){
                alert('test');
                return false;
        }
        return base;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I know I can use

```
base.on("dragover", function(e) {
   alert('test');
     e.preventDefault(); 
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

instead, and that works and is the jQuery equivalent, but I want to know why the javascript isn't working?

Comment: Why do you want to use `base.ondragover` instead of `base.on("dragover")`?

Comment: Well since posting I have been changing it to the jQuery equivalent which is the code underneath. I was just puzzled why the javascript code wasn't working. It works if I use it with an id outside of my plugin, but does not work in my plugin. To further my learning I wanted to learn why the javascript would not work in my plugin. I will probably use the jQuery alternative, but I just wanted to know why, as usually you can mix jQuery and javascript code.

Comment: It's better to use `foo.on("bar")` (jQuery) or `foo.addEventListener("bar")` (native JS) than `foo.onbar`, as you can add and remove multiple listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base=$(this)` is a jQuery object, and jQuery object doesn't have `.dragover` property, but DOM object has.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense. So if I wanted to use the javascript all I would have to do is to get the id from the base and then it would probably work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
base.dragover(function(){})
```